# Javascript illustrator loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, layer

I am trying to send pathitems to the back of the layer via their selection order, but for some reason as the loop iterates though the selection[i] index it doesn't return them in order

```
var openDoc = app.activeDocument;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  var topObject = app.activeDocument.selection[i];
  var activelayer = topObject.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDTOBACK);
}
```

but if I try to unfold the loop it works:

```
var openDoc = app.activeDocument;

var topObject = app.activeDocument.selection[0];
var activelayer = topObject.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDTOBACK);

var topObject2 = app.activeDocument.selection[1];
var activelayer = topObject.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDTOBACK);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In the first code block you have 3 loops, I don't know if this change something in your script. You could put a console.log at the end of the loops just to see if topObject is as you expect

Comment: it's not it changes order

Comment: can you reproduce the bug on jsfiddle?

Comment: i think its because the selection array foes not hold the selections in order it holds them at random